# PromQL: identify the metrics that keep rising in time range

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

It's about to monitor Kafka lag as sometimes the consumer stuck without error raised.

Here is thought... warning is supposed to be sent, if the lag by certain "consumergroup, topic" keeps rising in 20m (20 samples), which means the neighboring sample either goes up or goes evenly during the period.

Is there a way to define this trigger in promql?

Element example:

```
kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="order-beta",endpoint="http",instance="172.20.58.226:9308",job="kafka-exporter",namespace="monitoring",partition="0",pod="kafka-exporter-885fbcb9f-g9ktq",service="kafka-exporter",topic="health.check"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier). For example, the following PromQL query would return non-empty result when the current value for `kafka_consumergroup_lag` exceeds the value 20 minutes ago:

```
kafka_consumergroup_lag > kafka_consumergroup_lag offset 20m
```

Try using this query in Prometheus alerts.